# Fermion creation operator in boson basis

Tags: condensed-matter, operators, bosonization

I've been reading Giamarchi, Quantum Physics in One Dimension, Chapter 2 on 1d bosonization, and in appendix B.1, he derives equation B.2, which represents the fermion creation operator $\psi_r (x)$ with bosonic operators and the ladder operator $U_r$, but I don't understand how he did this, especially where the $\epsilon$ came from.
$$
\begin{align}
\psi_r^{\dagger}(x) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}} e^{-irk_Fx}e^{i\phi_r^\dagger(x)}U_r^\dagger e^{i\phi_r(x)}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1{\sqrt{2\epsilon L}}e^{-i r(k_F-\pi/L)x}e^{i\phi_r^\dagger(x)+i\phi_r(x)}U_r^\dagger 
\tag{B.9}
\end{align}
$$

If anyone has gone over the derivation, it would be appreciated if you could elaborate.

EDIT: I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9805275) by Jan von Delft, which explains this pretty well, especially pages 16-17 and the appendix.

Comment: I added MathJax, please use it in the future for typesetting math. See [guide](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and links therein.

Comment: This was first derived by just noticing that combinations of these operators had the correct commutation relations to represent the creation (and with a hermitian conjugate, destruction) of fermion modes.  Rigorous derivations were first given in F. D. M. Haldane, J. Phys. C 14 2585 (1981) and R. Heidenreich, R. Seiler, D. A. Uhlenbrock, J. Stat. Phys. 22, 27 (1980).

Comment: @Buzz I've read Haldane before, but he only wrote down the equation in (3.37) and claiming it can be trivially obtained, which I'm not quite sure why. I also don't see where the $\epsilon$ comes from. I haven't read the other paper though.